# The inner workings of glibc's free()

Tags: c, heap-memory, free, glibc

For glibc 2.15 I was looking at malloc.c, specifically the free() function, and became confused about the unlink() macro. According to the source a chunk in use looks like this:

```
   chunk-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
                  Size of previous chunk, if allocated            
           +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
                  Size of chunk, in bytes                       
     mem-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
                  User data starts here...                          .
    .                                                               .
    .             (malloc_usable_size() bytes)                      .
    .                                                               
nextchunk->+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

and a free()'d chunk looks like this:

```
    chunk-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
                         Size of previous chunk                    
            +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 `head:'           Size of chunk, in bytes                          
  mem->     +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
                  Forward pointer to next chunk in list             
            +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
                  Back pointer to previous chunk in list            
            +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
                  Unused space (may be 0 bytes long)                .
    .                                                               .
    .                                                               
nextchunk-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

When a used chunk is free()'d it takes the mem pointer it received as an argument and subtracts an offset from it to get a chunk pointer. There are a bunch of checks in between but in the case that the chunk wasn't mmapped it usually forward- or backward-consolidates it with another free chunk. Since the chunk being free()'d is already in a bin it just searches within that particular bin for chunks to consolidate it with, correct? In the case of forward consolidation the `unlink()` macro is called and applied to the chunk that follows the chunk being free()'d. I don't understand this because when the next chunk (call it 'nextchunk') is unlinked the following code occurs:

```
    #define unlink(P, BK, FD) {                                            
    FD = P->fd;                                                          
    BK = P->bk;
    .
    .
    .
    FD->bk = BK;                                                       
    BK->fd = FD;
    .
    .
    .
                             }
```

How can `BK->fd` be referenced considering that BK points to the chunk being free()'d and looking at its structure it does not have a forward or backward pointer. I must have missed the part in the code where the fd and bk fields are added to the chunk being free()'d but I don't know where. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line creates a forward pointer in the chunk being freed:

```
BK->fd = FD;
```

BK *used* to be a chunk of user data, but *now* it's a chunk of free data so `malloc` is allowed to scribble over the memory as it sees fit.

If it helps, you can think of it like a union:

```
union {
    struct {
        chunk *fd;
        chunk *bk;
    } freed;
    unsigned char user_data[N];
};
```

In a union, you're allowed to *write* into any of the union members, but you can only *read* from the most recently written member.  So when `free` is called, data is written to `fd` and `bk` -- which is okay, the only consequence is that `user_data` might have garbage now.  By comparison, when the chunk contains user data (not free), then the `fd` and `bk` pointers are garbage since they alias `user_data`.

(Technically, you can always read from `user_data` no matter what aliases it since it's an `unsigned char`, but that isn't really relevant.)

**Update:** This is *low-level* C code.  You'd expect low-level C code in a `malloc` implementation.  The idea that a field exists or does not exist does not make sense in low-level code, since we are casting to and from different types and allowing pointers to alias each other.

In low-level code, a field is just a memory offset.  On my system, the `fd` field might have an offset of 0, and the `bk` field might have an offset of 8 or 4, depending on the architecture I compile for.  So the following code:

```
BK->fd = FD;
```

This means "write the value FD to the memory location BK + 0".  If you think of `BK->fd` as just a location in memory, it may help you understand how `free` works.  (It's not actually *just* a location in memory, since at compile-time there is also type information and aliasing rules.)

**Understanding low-level C:**  If you want to understand low-level C code, it helps *immensely* to understand assembly language.  It's not necessary, but it helps.  It doesn't matter which assembly language you learn: x86, MIPS, PowerPC, ARM, etc.  You don't need to learn much assembly, just a little bit.  You don't need to learn x86, you can learn MIPS even if you never use MIPS.  (In fact, MIPS is probably easier to learn.)

Just learn enough assembly that you can translate a small piece of C code into assembly so you can understand what it's doing under the hood.  That one line of C code above probably translates into one line of assembly code, because it's so simple.

And try not to think about assembly much when you're *writing* C.  When you're writing C, the compiler's writing assembly, which means *you aren't* writing assembly.

Comment: So the chunk that was originally malloc()'d already had the fd and bk fields correct? They are labeled as "user data". But wouldn't that mean that no data could be written to the first x bytes of user data so that fd and bk would not be overwritten?

Comment: When the chunk is passed to `free`, the `free` function writes in the `fd` and `bk` fields.  The fields overlap with user data, but that's okay since the user data is unused for freed chunks.

Comment: But since BK=nextchunk->bk BK is a pointer to the top of the chunk being free()'d and when BK->fd=FD is called doesn't this just "reference" the field fd or is it actually creating fd within BK and setting it equal to FD?

Comment: Mabye I should take a look at the inital struct created when malloc is called to create the memory that is now being free. I do know x86 assembly and understand the concept of "existence" within code but when an offset that has no meaning is referenced this wouldn't work. So when the chunk that is being free()'d was malloc()'d its struct would have had to have defined this somewhere...I'm going to check the source again.

Comment: 1+ for "When you're writing C, the compiler's writing assembly, which means you aren't writing assembly."